# Accidentally made an ext4 file system on my encrypted Windows 10 OS partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, encryption, format, ext4

I have two drives on my Windows 10 PC that are both encrypted using Bitlocker. I read somewhere that the only way to make sure the drives are actually encrypted is to boot a live OS and see if you can access them or not without unlocking the drives.

I wanted to pretend like I was penetration testing my own computer, so I burned Xubuntu on a flash drive and booted from it. I wanted to mount the C drive (OS drive) so I first did:

```
sudo mount -v /dev/sda4 /mnt/hdd
```

*(sda4 is the main OS partition)*

then since there was some error I did:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4
```

I believe the above command is precisely where I messed up. I had no idea what I was doing and was just googling running different things to see if I could get into the encrypted drive. For some reason my brain thought running all these random commands was fine since the drive was encrypted so obviously there was no damage I could do from a live OS, right?

After this I decided I was done and restarted my PC to boot back into Windows 10. This is where I realized I messed up. Instead of the boot screen I was met with "attemping to repair" (which ends up failing to fix every time) and now I can't boot into my OS.

So apparently now I've created an ext4 file system on my Windows 10 partition which I guess corrupted it in some way that Windows can't use it anymore. Are my files gone? I really don't know what to do. And I think the fact that my drives are encrypted with bitlocker makes the situation worse. I really appreciate any and all help

Comment: Sorry. The command `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4` formated the drive with the ext4 file system. This overwrote whatever was there before. I hope you have a backup of your most valuable data (documents, pictures etc) because it will be difficult or impossible to get the data back from the formated partition. The encryption makes things worse. If you are lucky, you may be able to repair the partition with **`testdisk`** . Without encryption, maybe it would work with `photorec` to recover files directly from the data storage on the drive ... See http://cgsecurity.org

Comment: Actually, did you use `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4 ` or did you just run `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda4 ` . You may not have formatted the partition if you did not use sudo. This may be a simple fix that the bootrec or fixboot windows commands can fix and/or windows was probably in some unstable or hibernated "fast boot" state that it can't wake up from now.  Please edit your question and post the error you got on the windows repair. Thanks!

Comment: @sudodus Don't you need to use `sudo` when you run `mkfs.ext4`?

Comment: Also, if the OS drive was formatted, I don't think you would get the repair option. The system should not boot at all if the OS drive was formatted.

Comment: @mchid, Yes, you need to use `sudo` when you run `mkfs.ext4`, so there is a chance that the OP has not really formated the drive. Let us hope so :-)